# Symfony 2.8 - Ivory Google Maps Bundle - Unrecognized option “api_key” under “ivory_google_map”

Tags: google-maps, symfony, google-maps-api-3, api-key

I have followed [master documentation](https://github.com/egeloen/IvoryGoogleMapBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/installation.md#download-the-bundle) and tried to download it's version of bundle by running:

```
$ composer require egeloen/google-map-bundle
```

But unfortunatelly it downloaded `2.2` version of a bundle. I would think that this is correct version, but it is not. When I follow the documentation further I get an error in configuration after adding this to config.yml:

```
ivory_google_map:
    api_key: "%api_key%"
```

Error says:

```
Unrecognized option “api_key” under “ivory_google_map”
```

[Here](https://github.com/egeloen/IvoryGoogleMapBundle/issues/176#issuecomment-246431610) creator says:

> Let me explain your issue, when refering to https://github.com/egeloen/IvoryGoogleMapBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/service/distance_matrix.md#api-key you're refering to dev-master doc whereas if you're using the 2.2.1 version, you should use: https://github.com/egeloen/IvoryGoogleMapBundle/blob/2.2.1/Resources/doc/usage/services/distance_matrix/distance_matrix.md
>
> Unfortunatelly for you, the api key support has only been added on
>   master, so if you want to take benefit of it, you will need to
>   upgrade.

Okay so I am 100% sure that documentation installation I followed downloaded wrong version and I have to upgrade it. But how?

I tried running:

```
$ composer require egeloen/google-map-bundle dev-master
```

And I got an error:

```
Problem 1
- Installation request for egeloen/google-map-bundle dev-master -> satisfiable by egeloen/google-map-bundle[dev-master].
- egeloen/google-map-bundle dev-master requires egeloen/google-map ^2.0@dev -> satisfiable by egeloen/google-map[2.0.x-dev] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
```

^2.0@dev does not solve my problem either. Please can anyone help? I cannot find any articles according this problem.

Comment: Can you post your `composer.json` file ? It might be because your `minimum-stability` is set to `stable` (default value), whereas if you want to use the master branch of a repository, you have to set this value to `dev`. The developer should have tag a new version though.

Comment: No such `minimum-stability` is set in my composer.json. Should I add it? Also I asked this issue in their GitHub, maybe they will edit their documentation afterwards.

Comment: If it's not set, yes, you should add it with `dev` value as explained here: https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability

Comment: Added and updated the composer. Now it reinstalled a bunch of bundles to dev-master. Should I worry about it? I am worried about stabilities

Comment: Yes, this is not a good practice. That's why it's sad that the developer had not retagged a version with the changes. You can prevent this by fixing your vendors version, but then you won't have the vendors updates automatically...

Comment: Could you post it as answer so I could accept it?

Comment: Done. :) I'm glad I could helped you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Composer has an option called [minimum-stability](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability) that is set by default to `stable`. This means that when you run `composer install` or `composer update`, composer will only accept properly tagged versions.

If you want to use the `dev-master` of a vendor, you will have to set the `minimum-stability` option to `dev` in your composer.json :

```
{
    "name": "myproject",
    ...
    "require": {
        ...
    },
    "require-dev": {
        ...
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    ...
}
```

Be aware that this could lead to non-stable versions of vendors being installed in your project, so this is to avoid when you can. You can also prevent this by setting the version of your vendors to be sure a specific tag will be used, but then you would have to check your vendors update manually.